# Why don't some devices return data via site to site VPN?

Tags: vpn, nas

I have set up a Ubiquiti UDM to UDM VPN. When connecting via a web browser using the remote IP addresses, some remote devices return data (e.g. Reolink doorbell returns live video) and others do not (e.g. Synology NAS, other cameras, etc).

I have tried different UDM VPN setups (Magic VPN, OpenVPN, IPSec) and they all appeared to connect successfully, so I assume it is not a UDM/Firewall/routing problem.

The one device which I would most like to connect to is the NAS. When I enter its address it looks like it is communicating but the login web page never appears, I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. When I try to connect to the remote printer I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Any ideas about the possible cause(s) and how to debug?

Comment: Are you connecting via system name or ip address?

Comment: When you are unable to connect to the NAS, is this happening, within your network or outside of your network? If it's outside of your network, then I assume you have forwarded the appropriate ports to the device, but that would prevent other devices on that same port to be accessible.

Comment: @GeneMoody Connecting via ip address - and all these devices are fixed ip, not dynamic.

Comment: Further clarification - these are 2 networks each with their own UDM router. The routers are connected via site to site VPN. I can ping all devices on the other network with no problem and even get video across the vpn from the doorbell, but some devices don't return data (web pages) and just return error messages as noted in my original posting.

Comment: As @ramhound suggested, do you know the ports are passed through for those devices? With firewalls betwixt, I would suggest them as being the culprit. Is the camera service that IS working perhaps cloud based and just seems to be working in this arrangement?

Comment: I've tried opening all the ports in the routers. I've tried disabling the firewall on the PC where the browser is. The camera service cannot be via the ethernet/cloud because I access the camera across the VPN via its local IP address, not by name.

Comment: @GenevaBrown - Traffic has to reach the device before a firewall, running on the device, becomes a problem.  If you are trying to access the device outside of your network, you will have to forward the appropriate ports, used by the device to manage it remotely.